# How should I attach heavy floating shelves to hollow plasterboard walls?

Tags: drywall, walls, kitchens, shelving, fitting

I have the following shelves, intended to be floating shelves, that we want to attach to our kitchen walls. The walls are hollow plasterboard, with no studs where we want to put these shelves.

[image: picture of 2 shelves]

They came with fixings like these, which are intended for solid walls or studs, 2 each for 2 pre-drilled holes in each shelf.

[image: picture of shelf fixing]

The measurements are as follows:

- shorter shelf: 5.5kg, 75x22x6.5cm
- longer shelf: 7.5kg, 105x22x6.5cm

We won't be putting anything extremely heavy on the shelves, but they will probably need to hold quite a bit more weight than just themselves, just in case (maybe double their own weight?).

I'm guessing I'll need to use a different fixing for these, one that is designed for hollow walls.

My questions are:

1. Is it reasonable to expect these to work as floating shelves or would it be more secure to use brackets (not totally opposed to this, but would prefer another option if possible)?
2. If yes, what kind of fixings should I look for to securely attach these shelves to the wall?
3. Would it help to drill any extra holes in each shelf so that they're attached at more than 2 points?

Comment: These shelves just push onto the pins you screw in, so you don't have access to tighten the fastener up to allow using something like a toggle bolt. Are they not wide enough that they pass over a stud at any point? If they do, re-drill the holes to use the supplied hardware at the studs.

Comment: @PhilG - there is a single stud on the left side where the small shelf should go, and there's a stud right in the centre of where the large shelf should go. Don't know if this will be sufficient (and will still need other fixings). Unfortunately the shelves fit exactly into 2 gaps between 2 walls, so there isn't too much leeway to adjust where they go to be over studs.

Comment: I don't think the plasterboard mounts will hold in the long run. The outward force from the shelves will be leveraged by their width.  Imagine pushing down on the outer edge of the shelf.   I hope you are good at repairing plaster holes!

Comment: I would open the wall and put cross bracing between all studs at the height need for attaching the shelves. I do not think it is wise to have only two drywall anchors per shelve holding these up. If you do use anchors i would use these,  https://www.amazon.com/TOGGLER-SNAPTOGGLE-Drywall-included-Fastener/dp/B005C4YE4M?psc=1&SubscriptionId=AKIAILSHYYTFIVPWUY6Q&tag=duckduckgo-ffsb-20&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B005C4YE4M

Comment: I believe adding additional support is the only way this will work. If the op try’s and fails they will have some big holes to patch,,, better off to cut it out now add bracing and patch the walls. If careful no new Sheetrock will be needed just patches.+

Comment: Would really rather avoid opening up the wall, would prefer to use brackets if that's the only way. Given the position of the studs, I think I could drill another hole and attach the longer shelf to the stud in the centre, and attach the shorter shelf to a stud on its left side; I could then use 2 snap toggles for the pre-drilled holes in the longer one, and 1 for the right side of the shorter one. Do you think this would be sufficient?